# beginner prolog: data structures

Tags: data-structures, prolog

I'm trying to get my head around Prolog, and I am struggling somewhat with data structures.

I want to take a `point(X,Y)` and reflect it along the "diagonal" `X=Y`, so a `point(-5,8)` becomes `point(8,-5)`.

```
/* the following line is what I've gotten so far, 
   but I don't know how to manipulate the data inside the structures. */
reflection(X,Y) :- =(Y,X).

test_answer :-
    reflection(point(-5,8), point(X,Y)),
    write(point(X, Y)).
test_answer :-
    write('Wrong answer!').
```

Should output `point(8,-5)`.

Does this sort of thing even need data structures or am I over-thinking it?

Comment: I've figured out a solution, but it seems bad, to me.
    'reflection(point(A,B),point(P,Q)):- =(point(P,Q),point(B,A)).'

Comment: The solution you found is correct. The same can be expressed more compactly; below answers by users 'Enigmativity' and 'peak' show you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just write:

```
reflection(point(A,B), point(B,A)).
```

If that is in the file reflection.prolog, then:

```
$ gprolog --consult-file reflection.prolog
...
| ?- reflection( point(1,2), X).
X = point(2,1)
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The version of prolog I use (Strawberry Prolog) doesn't allow me to use the prefix notation for `=`, so unless you prolog has a different meaning for `=` then it appears that your code is this:

```
reflection(X,Y):- Y = X.
```

Which means that `reflection\2` will only unify when the `X` & `Y` are unifiable.

So your code should result in `point(-5,8)` and not `point(8,-5)` as `point(-5, 8)` is unifiable with `point(X, Y)` when `X = -5` & `Y = 8`. You don't say what you do get in your question.

You need to use this rule to make it work:

```
reflection(point(X,Y),point(Y,X)).
```